# does equi join return duplicate column

Tags: sql, join

Consider following points:

1. As we know, `inner join` returns the duplicate column for which we have defined the joining condition.
2. And we know `natural join` it removes the duplicate.
3. I know we can use equi join:

   ```
   select * from table1, table2 where id1=id2
   ```

   or

   ```
   select * from table1 join table2 on id1 = id2
   ```

I have confusion in this third point. I want to know what is the scenario in equi join what it returns? Does it return with duplicate column where we have defined the joining condition like `inner join`.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Only JOIN USING () and NATURAL JOIN remove columns. (Avoid those...)

Comment: @jarlh does any type of join (Left outer join,natural join ,inner join etc) followed by using keyword removes columns

Comment: Please use modern join syntax. Avoid comma-separated old join syntax (from 1989, the year of the lambada).

Comment: Second tip of today: Avoid `SELECT *` and explicitly define columns to avoid duplicates. See [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/1422451)

Comment: @user10891599, yes, all `USING ()` joins remove columns, same for all `NATURAL JOIN`s.

Comment: SQL is not relational algebra. "Equijoin" is a relational algebra term, not a SQL term, although it is used informally. (And there are many relational algebras, even with different notions of relation.)  So what do you mean by it? And how are you stuck understanding that definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer titled question: Yes, if your query uses `SELECT *`. While your focus is on the `JOIN` clause, you are forgetting fundamentals about the `SELECT` clause in SQL.

By the way your #3 (your definition of *equi join*) is equivalent to #1  (`inner join`). In #3, the former using `WHERE` is the older, de-emphasized (ANSI-89) implicit join style and the latter using `JOIN` is the current, standard (ANSI-92) explicit join. Both return same results and should render same performance but readability arguably differs. *See* [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44917/1422451).

The reason you receive duplicate columns for these *equi-join* cases is the `SELECT` clause requests for *all* columns of *all* joined tables since you do not qualify the asterisk,`*`:

```sql
select * from table1 join table2 on id1 = id2
```

However, using asterisk alone is an abbreviated, convenience method but the recommended way is to explicitly control your resultset by selecting specific columns. This is crucial for application builds where column order and existence is required and helps in code readability and maintainability. *See* [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/1422451)

Below are examples that can be used to avoid duplicate columns: qualifying the asterisks, subsetting/omiting columns, and even renaming/re-ordering columns with aliases .

```sql
-- ONLY table1 COLUMNS
select table1.* from table1 join table2 on id1 = id2

-- ONLY table2 COLUMNS
select table2.* from table1 join table2 on id1 = id2


-- SUBSET OF table1 AND table2 COLUMNS
select table1.Col1, table1.Col2, table1.Col3
     , table2.Col4, table2.Col5, table2.Col6 
from table1 
join table2 on id1 = id2


-- RENAMED COLUMNS
select table1.Col1 as t1_col1, table1.Col2 as t1_col2, table1.Col3 as t1_col3
     , table2.Col3 as t2_col3, table2.Col2 as t2_col2, table2.Col1 as t2_col1
from table1 
join table2 on id1 = id2
```